# Is there any simple and clear way to search values in arbitrary deep branchy objects?

Tags: javascript, json, object, search

I see one smart way: using `JSON.stringify` to recursively traverse objects like this:

```js
function search(obj, str) {
  let flag = false;

  JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === "object") return value;
    else {
      // doesn't take into account Date cases etc
      if (value.indexOf(str) >= 0) {
        flag = true;
      }
    }
  })

  return flag;
}
```

P.S: Not sure about tags.

Comment: please add an example of the data and the wanted result.

Comment: Usually the answer with trees is some form of recursion.

Comment: Yes, there is a simple and clear way to search values in trees: [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). You really should not use `JSON.stringify` for this!

Comment: @NinaScholz just some nested object with multiple layers like 
`{a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb', c: { d: 'ddd', e: { f: 'fff', g: 'ggg' } }}`

Comment: @Bergi What's the difference between DFS and BFS in my case? Because I need to check all values in a worst case scenario. As I get [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Syntax), `stringify` runs in a BFS style.

Comment: @NinaScholz I just want to know does my object contains particular substring in any value.

Comment: @totalamd You asked for a simple way - and DFS is much simpler than BFS.

Comment: @totalamd Btw, no, `JSON.stringify` descends depth-first as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use a traditional iterative and recursive approach by using a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

```js
function findString(object, string) {
    return Object.keys(object).some(k => typeof object[k] === 'object'
        ? findString(object[k], string)
        : object[k].includes(string)
    );
}

var object = { a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb', c: { d: 'ddd', e: { f: 'fff', g: 'ggg' } } };

console.log(findString(object, 'ggg'));
console.log(findString(object, 'foo'));
```